# Is there any way to make a timeseries scatterplot with array sizing in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I'm trying to make a scatterplot with time series data in a Pandas DataFrame. I would like to make the size of the markers proportional to values in an array.

`matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date(x, y)` won't work because it won't accept a marker size argument.

When I try to use `plt.scatter`, it returns an `invalid type promotion` error.

Are there any alternatives that might be worth trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this df:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = {'col1': ['2017-12-01','2017-12-02','2017-12-03', '2017-12-04'],
      'col2': [5,10,20,30]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
df['col1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col1'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
x = df['col1']
y = df['col2']
print df
         col1  col2
0  2017-12-01     5
1  2017-12-02    10
2  2017-12-03    20
3  2017-12-04    30
```

and this array:

```
a =[1,5,10,20]
```

You can try so:

```
for index, i in enumerate(a):
    plt.plot(df.iloc[index][0], df.iloc[index][1], marker='.', linestyle='None', markersize=i*2, color='r')
plt.show()
```

[image]